# How we can get and show the exact user location in map in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, geolocation

i want to show the user location along with the street name in a map? i also got one link but working in internet explorer only but that is always asking for "do u want to share location 
" as popup.

Please help me in this problem

Comment: So, what's your problem? That your code doesn't work in other browsers? Or that you want to avoid the popup?

Comment: i want to avoid the popup and my code does not work in other browsers is the problem too.

Comment: You'll not be able to circumvent the popup. That's a privacy issue. I do not want to share which dark basement I'm currently dwelling in. Also, show us the code that doesn't work in other browsers.

Comment: code does not work in internet explorer. it was working in Firefox now the permission is just appering and then faded away.
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: i'm not able to get the values longitude and latitude from it.